# python pandas - add unique Ids in column from master df back in to processed dfs stored in list of dataframes

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops

I have a single df that includes multiple json strings per row that need reading and normalizing.

I can read out the json info and normalize the columns by storing each row as a new dataframe in a list - which i have done with the code below.

However I need to append the original unique Id in the original df (i.e. 'id': ['9clpa','g659am']) - which is lost in my current code.

The expected output is a list of dataframes per Id that include the exploded json info, with an additional column including Id (which will be repeated for each row of the final df).

I hope that makes sense, any suggestions are very welcome. thanks so much

**dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['9clpa','g659am'],'i2': [('{"t":"unique678","q":[{"qi":"01","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"G","value":"3"},{"answer":"V","value":"4"}]},{"qi":"02","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"A","value":"3"},{"answer":"B","value":"4"},{"answer":"G","value":"5"},{"answer":"NC","value":"6"},{"answer":"O","value":"7"} ]}]}'),('{"t":"unique428","q":[{"qi":"01","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"G","value":"3"},{"answer":"V","value":"4"}]},{"qi":"02","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"A","value":"3"},{"answer":"B","value":"4"},{"answer":"G","value":"5"},{"answer":"NC","value":"6"},{"answer":"O","value":"7"} ]}]}')]})
```

**current code**

```
out={}
for i in range(len(df)):
    out[i] = pd.read_json(df.i2[i])
    out[i] = pd.json_normalize(out[i].q)
```

**expected output**

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['9clpa','9clpa'],'qi': ['01','02'], 'answers': ['{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"G","value":"3"},{"answer":"V","value":"4"}', '"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"A","value":"3"},{"answer":"B","value":"4"},{"answer":"G","value":"5"},{"answer":"NC","value":"6"},{"answer":"O","value":"7"']})
pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['g659am','g659am'],'qi': ['01','02'], 'answers': ['{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"G","value":"3"},{"answer":"V","value":"4"}', '"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"A","value":"3"},{"answer":"B","value":"4"},{"answer":"G","value":"5"},{"answer":"NC","value":"6"},{"answer":"O","value":"7"']})
```

Comment: Don't you think that instead of having multiple dataframes, expanding your first dataframe to have multiple lines would be better? Your `df` would have 4 lines, 2 with the ID '9c...' and 2 with the ID 'g6...'

Comment: @BeChillerToo thanks for your comment. I dont think that really matters as in the second command i apply pd.json_normalize to only one column, which is when i lose the id column from the original df. but indeed it could make it simpler in other ways

Comment: Can you paste the original JSON data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing on assigning the `id` to your dataframe after your normalize columns:

```
out={}
for i in range(len(df)):
    out[i] = pd.read_json(df.i2[i])
    out[i] = pd.json_normalize(out[i].q)
    out[i]['id'] = df.id[i]
    out[i] = out[i].loc[:, ['id','qi','answers']]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> out[0]
      id  qi                                                                                                                                                                                                                     answers
0  9clpa  01                                                                                                [{'answer': 'M', 'value': '1'}, {'answer': 'F', 'value': '2'}, {'answer': 'G', 'value': '3'}, {'answer': 'V', 'value': '4'}]
1  9clpa  02  [{'answer': 'M', 'value': '1'}, {'answer': 'F', 'value': '2'}, {'answer': 'A', 'value': '3'}, {'answer': 'B', 'value': '4'}, {'answer': 'G', 'value': '5'}, {'answer': 'NC', 'value': '6'}, {'answer': 'O', 'value': '7'}]
```

Comment: Iterating over the rows of a DataFrame is generally not the right way to do things

Comment: And the answer was to show what he missed in his approach that he is not getting expected result.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': ['9clpa','g659am'],'i2': [('{"t":"unique678","q":[{"qi":"01","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"G","value":"3"},{"answer":"V","value":"4"}]},{"qi":"02","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"A","value":"3"},{"answer":"B","value":"4"},{"answer":"G","value":"5"},{"answer":"NC","value":"6"},{"answer":"O","value":"7"} ]}]}'),('{"t":"unique428","q":[{"qi":"01","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"G","value":"3"},{"answer":"V","value":"4"}]},{"qi":"02","answers":[{"answer":"M","value":"1"},{"answer":"F","value":"2"},{"answer":"A","value":"3"},{"answer":"B","value":"4"},{"answer":"G","value":"5"},{"answer":"NC","value":"6"},{"answer":"O","value":"7"} ]}]}')]})
out={}
columns1 = ['id','qi','answers']
for i in range(len(df)):
    out[i] = pd.read_json(df.i2[i])
    out[i] = pd.json_normalize(out[i].q)
    df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=out[i],columns=columns1)
    df_new = df_new.assign(id = lambda x: df.id[i])
    display(df_new)
```

You can add a lambda function which will assign the value of 'id' to new df formed.

Edit: You can add location of 'id' column, in columns1 and define where you want it to appear when you create a dataframe.

Output dataframe:

[image]

Comment: As a general rule in pandas: if you are iterating over the rows, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I know but this solves the question asked. This answer was to show what was missed in the approach.

Comment: @AyushiRanjan thank you! this works for now - do you know if i can specify the location where the new id column should be added? i.e. at the first column

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how you can specify the location of 'id' column. Check it out if it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.json_normalize` (doc here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

(from https://medium.com/swlh/converting-nested-json-structures-to-pandas-dataframes-e8106c59976e)

Comment: Link only answers are not generally encouraged.